# Binary search (bisect) for a Unicode character in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a *sorted* list, `J`, of [2048 Japanese Unicode words](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/raw/master/mnemonic/wordlist/japanese.txt) which ideally I'd like to index using a binary search, as discussed in [this SO question *("Binary search (bisection) in Python)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python/2233940#2233940). The `binary_search` function uses `bisect_left` from the `bisect` module instead of indexing the list with the `list.index` function.

```
import bisect
def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None): # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a)   # hi defaults to len(a)
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi)  # find insertion point
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1)
```

Now, let's index each word in `words`:

```
words = "そつう　れきだい　ほんやく　わかす　りくつ　ばいか　ろせん　やちん　そつう　れきだい　ほんやく　わかめ"
```

Let's split to make a list:

```
>>> words.split()
[u'\u305d\u3064\u3046', u'\u308c\u304d\u305f\u3099\u3044', u'\u307b\u3093\u3084\u304f', u'\u308f\u304b\u3059', u'\u308a\u304f\u3064', u'\u306f\u3099\u3044\u304b', u'\u308d\u305b\u3093', u'\u3084\u3061\u3093', u'\u305d\u3064\u3046', u'\u308c\u304d\u305f\u3099\u3044', u'\u307b\u3093\u3084\u304f', u'\u308f\u304b\u3081']`)
```

Comparing `binary_search` with `list.index`:

```
>>> [ binary_search(J, x) for x in words.split()]
[-1, 2015, 1790, 2039, 1983, -1, 2031, 1919, -1, 2015, 1790, 2040]
>>> [ J.index(x) for x in words.split()]
[1019, 2015, 1790, 2039, 1983, 1533, 2031, 1919, 1019, 2015, 1790, 2040]
```

So for `u'\u305d\u3064\u3046'` (`そつう`), instead of an index of 1019, `binary_search` is returning an index of -1 (fail) since `pos` evaluates to **1027**, `u'\u305d\u3068\u304b\u3099\u308f'`. **Both words (index 1019 & 1027) begin with `u'\u305d'`, so that is where the issue seems to be.**

**How can `binary_search` be tweaked to find the index of a (Japanese) Unicode character?**

Comment: Binary search requires the input list to be sorted. Is your input sorted?

Comment: What is `J`? It is not your `words.split()` list. You cannot use the `words` value here as that is not a list but a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the list, J, *is* sorted. The code takes a Unicode mnemonic string; I've simplified it because of ideographic spaces used in Japanese. Binary_search is indexing words from a list, hence the split

Comment: The search works just fine if I use `J = sorted(words.split())`.

Comment: Ah, `J` is supposed to be the file loaded from github, split by lines? Did you strip whitespace? How did you load and sort that list?

Comment: When I load `J` from github with `J = sorted(requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/master/mnemonic/wordlist/japanese.txt').text.splitlines())` I get different output for the binary search and for the `J.index()` calls. The list is `[1024, 2015, 1787, 2039, 1983, 1601, 2031, 1919, 1024, 2015, 1787, 2040]` in both cases.

Comment: In other words, the binary search works *fine*, but your `J` list is not properly sorted or cleaned. I note that the discrepancies between my list and yours are also the points where the binary search fails, except for the two indices that are close to my results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [test.py](https://github.com/simcity4242/pybitcointools/blob/master/test.py#L563-L570). I see the issue now, if you want to put this into an answer I'll check it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your `J` list is at fault here; it is not correctly sorted.

When I use the `requests` library to load your test data file and sort the information, it works fine:

```
 >>> # your bisect function defined
 ...
 >>> import requests
 >>> words = u"そつう　れきだい　ほんやく　わかす　りくつ　ばいか　ろせん　やちん　そつう　れきだい　ほんやく　わかめ"
 >>> url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/master/mnemonic/wordlist/japanese.txt'
 >>> J = sorted(requests.get(url).text.splitlines())
 >>> [ J.index(x) for x in words.split()]
[1024, 2015, 1787, 2039, 1983, 1601, 2031, 1919, 1024, 2015, 1787, 2040]
>>> [ binary_search(J, x) for x in words.split()]
[1024, 2015, 1787, 2039, 1983, 1601, 2031, 1919, 1024, 2015, 1787, 2040]
```

Note that the indices don't quite match your test results; where the indices are off by more than 3 the bisect fails to find the result.