# Binary search Algorithm - Python

Tags: python

In python, while implementing the binary search algorithm, which math function is optimal to be used to find out the mid value - floor or ceil ?

Comment: optimal in what way?

Comment: Are these numerical values being searched? Or is it a general binary search?

Comment: Python has a builtin module [**`bisect`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) which has [examples of searching a sorted list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use either ceil or floor function for implementing binary search in python. Depending on the problem, you have to round the mid value up or down.

```
 mid = low + (high-low)/2 #rounds down the mid value
 mid = low + (high-low+1)/2 #rounds up the mid value
```

Try to solve these two problems, you will get an idea how this works.

1. Given an array A and a target value, return the index of the first element in A equal to or greater than the target value
2. Given an array A and a target value, return the index of last element which is smaller than target value.

First try these problems on your own and if you get stuck, refer to the [this.](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/)

Comment: Your use of `//` for comments is a bit confusing here.  I suggest using `//` for the division and `#` for comments.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about `floor` and `ceil`, there does not appear to be a more optimal option. You may want to find out [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python?rq=1) in this site.

Comment: I think your question needs to be a bit more concise in terms of what you are doing with the alogorithm, do you have any script of your work?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to use ceil or floor @shivam_mitra mentioned.
Here is a binary search algorithm if need it.

```
 def bSearch(L, e, low, high):
    """ 
    L: is a sorted list
    e: is the targeted number 
    low: is the lowest value of the list
    hight: is the highest value of list
    """
    if len(L) == 0:                 # empty list
        return False 

     if high == low:                    # if the list is one element 
        return L[low] == e

     mid = low + int((high - low)/2)

     if L[mid] == e:                    # If the midpoint is the targeted number 
        return True
     if L[mid] > e:                     # check if the number is in the lower half of the list
        return bSearch(L, e, low, mid - 1)
     else:                              # otherwire it is in the higher of the list
        return bSearch(L, e, mid + 1, high)
```