# Binary search of a number within a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was researching about  binary search of a number within a list and came across [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python)

Somewhere else I it was mentioned about going for even and odd numbered list separately. But is that language specific? The information is little confusing.

For Binary search , I know high-level I need to carry out following steps,

- sort the list in ascending order
- Check for middle item within a list  if thats the number we are done
- if not , if the number is  greater  than the middle number, get rid of lower half
- if searched  number is lower than middle number , get rid of uppeer half
- keep repeating until number is found

The list can be ascending or descending order and can be of `float` of `int` numbers.
what's pythonic way of carrying out above pseudocode?
I am using python 2.7.x on windows.

**  EDIT **
The mentioned discussion does not cover even and odd list (at least I couldn't see any
I would like to request more clarifications on that such as,
- If I need to treat even odd list differently
- Is there a way in python that will take care of that

Comment: The Pythonic way is [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2233940/1084416) to the linked question.

Comment: Also, see [the **`bisect`** source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/bisect.py#L67).

Comment: User also asked about `even` and `odd` list. my answer covers that.

Comment: @anil_M : Thanks for also covering `even , odd` list part of the question. Will the integer division work for both integers as well as float list. I will try out your code.

Comment: We are dividing number of elements rather than their values (float / int) etc.  Hence whether  your list has 10 int numbers or 10 float numbers `10 /3 will be still equal to 3`.  Also, you will need to replace main function accordingly to generate float list and float random number.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from bisect and ( as listed in discussion)  you can create your own function.
Below is a possible way this can be done.

If you use integer division within python , it will take care of even / odd list. As an e.g.  `10 / 3 = 3` and `9 / 3 = 3`.

**Sample Code**

```
import random
def binarySearch(alist, item):
        first = 0
        last = len(alist) - 1
        found = False

        while first<=last and not found:
            midpoint = (first + last)//2            
            if alist[midpoint] == item:
                found = True
            else:
                if item < alist[midpoint]:
                    last = midpoint-1
                else:
                    first = midpoint+1  
        return found

def findThisNum(mynum):

    testlist = [x for x in range(listlength)]

    print "testlist = ", testlist
    print "finding number ", mynum

    if (binarySearch(testlist, findnum)) == True:
        print "found %d" %mynum
    else:
        print "Not found %d" %mynum




#### Main_Function ####

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #

    #Search 1 [ Even numbered list ]
    listlength = 10    
    findnum = random.randrange(0,listlength)
    findThisNum(findnum)     

    #Search 2 [ [ Odd numbered list ]
    listlength = 13    
    findnum = random.randrange(0,listlength)
    findThisNum(findnum)

    #search 3  [ find item not in the list ]

    listlength = 13    
    findnum = random.randrange(0,listlength) + listlength
    findThisNum(findnum)
```

**Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
testlist =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
finding number  4
found 4
testlist =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
finding number  9
found 9
testlist =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
finding number  21
Not found 21
```

Comment: Hi, the solution works with both even and odd lists as well as float lists. Its easier to understand step by step concept.Tried manual float list for test purpose. - thanks.