# What are python's equivalents of std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound C++ algorithms?

Tags: python, binary-search

Does python provide functions for performing binary search on sorted lists, analogous to the `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` algorithms of the C++ Standard Library?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Those functions are located in the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module:

- bisect.**bisect_left**(*a*, *x*, *lo=0*, *hi=len(a)*) is the analog of `std::lower_bound()`.
- bisect.**bisect_right**(*a*, *x*, *lo=0*, *hi=len(a)*) is the analog of `std::upper_bound()`.

Note: there is also a function **bisect**() which is an alias for **bisect_right**().

Answer (score 0):

There is also `sortedcontainers` package in python, which also has `bisect_left` and `bisect_right`. https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html

This could be handy if you don't want to maintain the list sorted yourself (e.g. insertion).