# How to get the index of an element with std::upper_bound()?

Tags: c++

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873954/what-are-pythons-equivalents-of-stdlower-bound-and-stdupper-bound-c-algor), the use of `std::upper_bound()` and `std::lower_bound()` were discussed. However, the question focused on getting the `element`, and in this post, I am focused on getting the `index` of the element. The particular problem I have is as follows. I have a cumulative distribution of a random variable (let's say shirt color).

- white : 0.5
- black : 0.6
- green : 0.8
- blue  : 1.0

I will generate a random number uniformly between [0, 1.0] and then need to map that back to the cumulative probability. For example, if the random number is in [0, 0.5), then "white", if the random number number is in [0.5, 0.6) then "black", and so on.

I might store my probabilities in `std::vector<double>`, but `std::upper_bound()` and `std::lower_bound()` will return an iterator to access the element, not the index. That is fine, but then I will need perhaps a `std::map<double, std::string>` to map the double back to the string value.

In the context of what I am trying to achieve, is there a way to get the index of an element like with Python's `bisect` method?

Comment: You are using a vector? Just subtract `vec.begin()` from the iterator to get the index.

Comment: What @john said. There is an example in the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: @arc-menace That is the right answer. Thanks.