# Optimize Binary Search

Tags: python, binary-search

I am new to python, and very much enthusiastic to learn algorithm.
I have written sample code for Binary search, can any one suggest how can i achieve same result in more pythonic way (Optimize the code, or using Bisect if any way possible)?

```
def bee_search(alist, target):
    sort_list = sorted(alist)

    while len(sort_list) >= 1:
        end = len(sort_list)
        middle = int((0 + end)/2)

        if target == sort_list[middle]:
            print "Found it", str(sort_list[middle])
            break
        elif target > sort_list[middle]:
            sort_list = sort_list[middle:]
        elif target < sort_list[middle]:
            sort_list = sort_list[:middle]
        else:
            return "Fount it", str(sort_list[middle])

    else:
        print "List is Empty"

arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
bee_search(arr,15)
```

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233940/4385319

Comment: maybe you will also be interested in this website: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBinarySearch.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably this answers part of your question. You don't really need to get the middle index, you can compare the maximum value in `alist` with `target`:

```
def bee_search(alist, target):
    largest = max(alist)
    if target == largest: 
        print "Found", target
    elif target < largest: 
        print"Found", target
    else:                  # target > largest
        print("Not found")
```

This is okay when `target == largest` and when `target > largest` but not when `target < largest`, yes this is a broken algorithm!

```
arr = [1,0,2,3, 10, 200, 5, 29, 10, 39, 109]
bee_search(arr, 30)
```

When run this is the output:`Found 30`.

This problem applies to your algorithm too, a simple comparison cannot tell us definitely whether `alist` has a reference for integer `30`. You may need to consider workarounds, don't give up.