# Python: Search a sorted list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, list, search

**Useful information:**

For information on how to sort a list of various data types see:
[How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

.. and for information on how to perform a binary search on a sorted list see: [Binary search (bisection) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python)

**My question:**

How can you neatly apply binary search (or another log(n) search algorithm) to a list of some data type, where the key is a inner-component of the data type itself? To keep the question simple we can use a list of tuples as an example:

```
x = [("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c",3)]
binary_search(x, "b") # search for "b", should return 1
# note how we are NOT searching for ("b",2) yet we want ("b",2) returned anyways
```

*To simplify even further: we only need to return a single search result, not multiple if for example ("b",2) and ("b",3) both existed.*

**Better yet:**

How can we modify the following simple code to perform the above operation?

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):  # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a)  # hi defaults to len(a)   
    pos = bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi)  # find insertion position
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1)  # don't walk off the end
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: I am *not* looking for the complete algorithm itself. Rather, I am looking for the application of some of Python's standard(ish) libraries, and/or Python's other functionalities so that I can easily search a sorted list of some arbitrary data type at any time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of how lexicographic ordering deals with tuples of unequal length:

```
# bisect_right would also work
index = bisect.bisect_left(x, ('b',))
```

It may sometimes be convenient to feed a custom sequence type to `bisect`:

```
class KeyList(object):
    # bisect doesn't accept a key function, so we build the key into our sequence.
    def __init__(self, l, key):
        self.l = l
        self.key = key
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.key(self.l[index])

import operator
# bisect_right would *not* work for this one.
index = bisect.bisect_left(KeyList(x, operator.itemgetter(0)), 'b')
```

Comment: Modifying line 5 of the simple binary search algorithm to:
pos = bisect_left(a, (x,), lo, hi)  # find insertion position
... does not have the desired effect and returns a -1 not found.

Comment: @StephenLasky: I'm just showing you how to find the index. Your `binary_search` function has other problems; for example, it's comparing `x` to `a[pos]` directly, so it doesn't understand that it's found the right entry.

Comment: My mistake, everything works perfectly. Out of curiosity: how could you modify the above property to search for say the Nth position?

Comment: @StephenLasky: I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

What about converting the list of tuples to a dict?

```
>>> d = dict([("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c",3)])
>>> d['b'] # 2
```

Comment: The problem here is that I am dealing with massive lists (>1,000,000) and this kind of operation would simply be too slow. I appreciate your response though.