# Best way to get higest value in a matrix array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

i need to check the higest value of a array but in my case its taking to long:

My array have 3 values:
X, Y , Value

```
[
 [1,1,36],
 [1,2,36.5],
 [1,3,36.5],
 [1,4,36.5],
 [1,5,36.5],
 [2,1,36.5],
 [2,2,36.5],
 [2,3,36.5],
 [2,4,36.5],
 [2,5,36.5],
 [3,1,36.5],
 [3,2,36.5],
 [3,3,36.5],
 [3,4,36.5],
 [3,5,36.5],
]
```

note that my array is a x,y value for a pixel and the last info is a `float` value for it.

but its a small example i. Im my real case i will have 300.000 itens in my array.
Id like to get the higest value inside a starting x,y and ending x,y points.

I did a `for` function but its taking to long to execute.

some one can help me ?

#

i have another array now that i need to get the higest value
where i only have `[x,y]` values and to get temperatire i must to it:

```
value = image_data[x,y]
```

in the folowing exemple by DarrylG i dont know how to change it to work in this way.

i Tryed to change this line

```
return max(lst[index_lo:index_hi+1], key=lambda item: item[2])
```

to

```
return max(lst[index_lo:index_hi+1], key=lambda item: lst[0,1])
```

but it dont worked.

Comment: Please can you provide the code you use? so we can see how we can improve? Secondly, you used curly brace "{" for a list we expect to  see square bracket '[', please edit or give us more information about your data type.

Comment: Do you mean to have '[]' rather than '{}', so `[
 [1,1,36],
 [1,2,36.5],
 [1,3,36.5],
 [1,4,36.5],
 [1,5,36.5],
 [2,1,36.5],
 [2,2,36.5],
 [2,3,36.5],
 [2,4,36.5],
 [2,5,36.5],
 [3,1,36.5],
 [3,2,36.5],
 [3,3,36.5],
 [3,4,36.5],
 [3,5,36.5],
]' for data?

Comment: Please give us: the expected input and output in their correct format, or to say, data structure, instead of something like this. Something like this, `{1,2,3}`, is called `set` in Python which is a **UNORDERED** collection with **UNIQUE** elements. That's can't be your true data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumption 1**

Since using {} doesn't make sense, I'm assuming your values are:

```
my_lst = [
 [1,1,36],
 [1,2,36.5],
 [1,3,36.5],
 [1,4,36.5],
 [1,5,36.5],
 [2,1,36.5],
 [2,2,36.5],
 [2,3,36.5],
 [2,4,36.5],
 [2,5,36.5],
 [3,1,36.5],
 [3,2,36.5],
 [3,3,36.5],
 [3,4,36.5],
 [3,5,36.5],
]
```

**Assumption 2**

The first two values (i.e. X, Y) are ordered in ascending order (as in your example data).

**Assumption 3**

From your comments, the real problem you're trying to solve is to find max value over a limited range of the (X, Y) values.

**Solution**

We can't simply use ([Examples using max key](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/max)):

```
print(max(my_lst, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

Since this finds the tuple with max value over the entire list.  We want to find the max over a sublist.

We need a quick method to find the start and stop index in our list of tuples.

The sublist is specified by indexes of (X, Y) start/stop locations such as: start: (2, 1), finish: (3, 4).

We use the method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155345/python-search-a-sorted-list-of-tuples) which allows a binary search to find the start and stop indexes.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
class KeyList(object):
    # bisect doesn't accept a key function, so we build the key into our sequence.
    def __init__(self, l, key):
        self.l = l
        self.key = key
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.key(self.l[index])

def find_max(lst, lo, hi):
  " Finds max within sublist of lo to hi tuples "

  # Binary search to find index of lo and hi pixel tuples
  index_lo = bisect_left(KeyList(lst, lambda y: (y[0], y[1])), start)
  index_hi = bisect_left(KeyList(lst, lambda y: (y[0], y[1])), finish)

  # Use slice to get sublist
  # Max based upon key which uses 3rd element of tuples
  return max(lst[index_lo:index_hi+1], key=lambda item: item[2])
```

**Usage**

```
print(find_max(my_lst, (2,1), (3,4)))
```

**Output**

```
[2, 1, 36.5]
```

**Additional Question**

In your additional question the data is actually a 2d array or grid of points.

For this type of data we don't need binary search to find where data starts and ends.

```
def find_max_grid(lst, lo, hi):
  " Find max within a 2d array given starting and stopping tuples "
  def max_with_index(row):
    " Finds max in a row "
    return max(enumerate(row), key=lambda v: v[1])

  r1, c1 = lo  # Starting row & column
  r2, c2 = hi  # Ending row & column

  max_row, max_col, max_val = -1, -1, 0  # Initial
  for r, row in enumerate(lst[r1:r2+1], start = r1):
    if r == r1:
      index, val  = max_with_index(row[c1:])
    elif r == r2:
      index, val = max_with_index(row[:c2+1])
    else:
      index, val = max_with_index(row)

    if val > max_val:
      max_row = r
      max_col = index
      max_val = val

  return (max_row, max_col), max_val
```

*Usage*

```
image_data = [
  [11, 12, 5, 2], 
  [15, 6, 10, 11], 
  [10, 8, 12, 5], 
  [12, 15, 8, 6]
  ]

# find max from row 1, column 2
# to            row 3, column 4
# rows and columns numbered are 0, 1, 2, ...
print(find_max_grid(image_data, [1, 2], [3, 4]))
```

**Output**

```
((3, 1), 15)  # row 3, column 1 with value 15
```

Comment: but i need to verify the highest value from a starting x,y like 2,1 and ending x,y 3,4

Comment: @JasarOrion--could you update your question with this criteria.

Comment: @JasarOrion--I updated my answer to reflect your comment.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: if i have a array only x,y and the value of it is the temperature how can i change this code? `value = image_data[x,y]`

Comment: @JasarOrion--I'm not sure if I understand.  Is image_data a 2d array of values corresponding to an image and x, y corresponds to pixel coordinates in the 2d image?

Comment: and i think this is  image is from a flir A615 thermal camera them the values correspond to the real temperature um Kelvin

Comment: @JasarOrion--added a case for this to my answer.  Does this work for you?

Comment: yes it does. i will implement in my cod. thank you so mutch

Comment: @JasarOrion--you're welcome.  Let me know if the performance is okay since it might be able to speed it up.

Comment: im trying to use your send function but it giviming ident errors. there is right to have a def inside another def ?

Comment: @JasarOrion--Here's a [link to running example code](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/SatisfiedElaborateShoutcast) which shows how things should be indented and you can run by hitting the run button.  A function deformed inside another is called [nested function](https://stackabuse.com/python-nested-functions/).