# How to efficiently check if a list of boxes overlap with each other?

Tags: python, geometry, lisp, autocad, autolisp

I wrote this code that checks if a list of boxes overlap with each other. This seems very insufficient though because I have to loop over each box multiplied by all of the other boxes. It there a better way to do this?

For simplicity sake and broader audience I wrote this in Python but the final implementation will be in AutoLISP because I'm using this inside of AutoCAD. For that reason I'm looking for a more general solution/algorithm that will work in any language and doesn't rely on any libraries.

```
from random import *
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")

class Box:
    
    def __init__(self):
        center = Point(x = randint(0, 100), y = randint(0, 100))
        self.UpperLeft  = Point(center.x - 2, center.y + 2)
        self.UpperRight = Point(center.x + 2, center.y + 2)
        self.LowerRight = Point(center.x + 2, center.y - 2)
        self.LowerLeft  = Point(center.x - 2, center.y - 2)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Box LL: {self.LowerLeft.x},{self.LowerLeft.y} and UR: {self.UpperRight.x},{self.UpperRight.y}"
        
    def Overlaps(self, box):
        if self.LowerLeft.x < box.UpperLeft.x < self.UpperRight.x and \
        self.LowerLeft.y < box.UpperLeft.y < self.UpperRight.y :
            return True
        
        if self.LowerLeft.x < box.UpperRight.x < self.UpperRight.x and \
        self.LowerLeft.y < box.UpperRight.y < self.UpperRight.y :
            return True
        
        if self.LowerLeft.x < box.LowerRight.x < self.UpperRight.x and \
        self.LowerLeft.y < box.LowerRight.y < self.UpperRight.y :
            return True
        
        if self.LowerLeft.x < box.LowerLeft.x < self.UpperRight.x and \
        self.LowerLeft.y < box.LowerLeft.y < self.UpperRight.y :
            return True
        
        return False
        

boxes  = [Box() for _ in range(300)]
for thisBox in boxes:
    multiplesFound = 0
    for otherBox in boxes:
        if thisBox is otherBox:
            continue
        elif thisBox.Overlaps(otherBox):
            print(f"{thisBox} overlaps with {otherBox}")
            multiplesFound += 1
    if multiplesFound >= 1:
        pass # highlight overlapping objects
```

Comment: Do you want to find every match, or should you be `break`-ing out of the `ranges` loop once you find a point within the range?

Comment: If you only want to know the maximum `max` and the minimum `min`, loop through `ranges` once to find them, then each `points` iteration will be a quick check.

Comment: @PeterWood Every match. I simplified the code by a lot but basically what I'm trying to do is: 1. build a map containing areas of where objects are in a drawing. 2. get the insertion points of each object. 3. Check each insertion point to see if it lands inside any of the areas. If we find more than one match that means there's a object overlap/collision.

Comment: You could sort your list first which is O(nlogn) and do a binary search seeing if it's in any of the ranges. That would result in a O(log n) search complexity I think.

Comment: For Binary Search you can use the [**`bisect`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python

Comment: Edited to show a better example

Comment: In multiple dimensions you want some sort of space-partitioning tree (a *k*-*d* tree augmented with bounding boxes or an interval tree works well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first level of optimization, of course, is to compare each box to only the following ones in the list. Ths is still O(n^2), but the actual number of comparisons is about `n**2 / 2`so it is a 2x speed-up.

Next step, you could split your plane in a few sub-areas, assign each box to its area and compare only the boxes in the same sub-area. The issue is, a box may have it lower left coordinate in a sub-area, and its upper right one in another sub-area, horizontally, vertically, or even in both directions. So we need to put that box in all the sub-areas it pertains to. But even with this further check, the speed-up is dramatic.

In the following, `check0()` is your original code, slightly modified in order to be able to use `timeit()`, `check1()` is the `n**2 / 2` version, `check2()` is the optimized version. `partition(splits)` is the helper function that creates the sub-area buckets. For instance `partition(4)` will create 4 x 4 sub-areas.

```
def partition(splits):
    for thisBox in boxes:
        threshold = 100 // splits
        llxPart = abs(thisBox.LowerLeft.x) // threshold
        llyPart = abs(thisBox.LowerLeft.y) // threshold
        partitions[(llxPart, llyPart)].append(thisBox)
        urxPart = abs(thisBox.UpperRight.x) // threshold
        uryPart = abs(thisBox.UpperRight.y) // threshold
        if urxPart > llxPart:
            partitions[(urxPart, llyPart)].append(thisBox)
        if uryPart > llyPart:
            partitions[(llxPart, uryPart)].append(thisBox)
            if urxPart > llxPart:
                partitions[(urxPart, uryPart)].append(thisBox)

def check0():
    totalMultiples = 0
    for thisBox in boxes:
        multiplesFound = 0
        for otherBox in boxes:
            if thisBox is otherBox:
                continue
            elif thisBox.Overlaps(otherBox):
                ##print(f"{thisBox} overlaps with {otherBox}")
                multiplesFound += 1
        if multiplesFound >= 1:
            pass # highlight overlapping objects
        totalMultiples += multiplesFound
    return totalMultiples

def check1():
    totalMultiples = 0
    for i,thisBox in enumerate(boxes):
        multiplesFound = 0
        for otherBox in boxes[i+1:]:
            if thisBox.Overlaps(otherBox):
                ##print(f"{thisBox} overlaps with {otherBox}")
                multiplesFound += 1
        if multiplesFound >= 1:
            pass # highlight overlapping objects
        totalMultiples += multiplesFound
    return totalMultiples

def check2():
    totalMultiples = 0
    for part in partitions.values():
        for i,thisBox in enumerate(part):
            multiplesFound = 0
            for otherBox in part[i+1:]:
                if thisBox.Overlaps(otherBox):
                    ##print(f"{thisBox} overlaps with {otherBox}")
                    multiplesFound += 1
            if multiplesFound >= 1:
                pass # highlight overlapping objects
            totalMultiples += multiplesFound
    return totalMultiples

from timeit import timeit
partition(4)

timeit("check0()", globals=globals(), number=1000)
6.7651189999999986

timeit("check1()", globals=globals(), number=1000)
3.5294421000000007

timeit("check2()", globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.45386700000000246
```